# How to match multiple instance with the same pattern in a matching using python

Tags: python, regex

Consider the following string as a example,

```
str = '(Obsoletes RFC0011) (Updated by RFC0036, RFC0047) (Status: UNKNOWN)'
```

I want to extract key-value pairs like this:

matchobj['Obsoletes'] = 'RFC0011'

matchobj['Updated by'] = ['RFC0036', 'RFC0047']

matchobj['Status'] = 'UNKNOWN'

How can I do it? NOTE: not all parenthesis are mandatory, such as '(Obsoletes RFC0011)' can not appear

My consideration is:
First, split the whole string by parenthesis pair and then extract from each parenthesis pair. To accomplish this, I have to match parenthesis using for or while statement, but I want to know if there is a way in Python to match multiple instance with the same pattern in a matching, it it is, i can access the match result from as a list or array

Maybe there is more better way to implement this, I'm primary for python and regular expression, if anyone give me some advice?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `(...)` parts and split them by capitalized words to solve the `Updated by` thing.

```
>>> s = '(Obsoletes RFC0011) (Updated by RFC0036, RFC0047) (Status: UNKNOWN)'
>>> data = [re.split(',?:?\s(?=[A-Z])',i) for i in re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)',s)]
>>> dic = {d[0]:d[1:] for d in data}
>>> dic
{'Status': ['UNKNOWN'],
 'Obsoletes': ['RFC0011'],
 'Updated by': ['RFC0036', 'RFC0047']}
```

You can optimize the arguments with only one element if you want.

If your Python is older than 2.7, use:

```
dict((d[0],d[1:]) for d in data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from re import split

splitted = split(r'\)\s\(', "(Obsoletes RFC0011) (Updated by RFC0036, RFC0047) (Status: UNKNOWN)")

obsoletes, updatedby, unknown = [[j for j in split(r'[\s,]', i) if "RFC" in j] for i in splitted]


matchobj = {"Obsoletes" : obsoletes, "UpdatedBy" : updatedby, "Unknown" : unknown}

print matchobj
```